# Разрешить индексацию favicon, при запрете индексации всего остального сайта

Tags: robots.txt, favicon

Всем привет, мой первый пост на stackoverflow

В чем суть:
Для роботов закрыта индексация на сайте через файл robots.txt

Вот что в файле:

> 1. User-Agent: *
> 2. Disallow: /

Но при таком раскладе блокируеся favicon при поиске сайта в яндексе/Гугле:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqgbv.jpg

Нашел решение, добавить строку в файл, разрешающий индексацию Фавиконки.
Прописал в robots.txt:

> 1. User-Agent: *
> 2. Disallow: /
> 3. Allow: /images/favicon/*

Вопрос: это правильное написание, если указан путь к папке, где лежат Фавиконки ?

P.S. просто, как написано, ждать изменений и появления фавкионки 2 недели и больше, хочу удостовериться что написал верно и робот, при следующей индексации, загрузит мои иконки )))

Спасибо, я не так давно этим занимаюсь, если что то криво объяснил, извините :с

Comment: Ничего не понял. Какой смысл манипуляций с иконками, если индексация сайта полностью запрещена и его вообще не должно существовать в результатах поиска?

Comment: Об этом я даже не задумывался. Клиент просил закрыть индексацию вообще 

Comment: На момент написания этого комментария сайт в гугле полностью отсутствует, а в яндексе отображается какое-то другое содержимое (8 июля и ранее), не соответствующее текущему содержимому сайта. Может, заказчик имел в виду не полностью запретить индексацию, а просто убрать из поиска старое содержимое, например?

Comment: Ну а если напрямую отвечать на (по-моему бессмысленный) вопрос — чтобы поисковик смог проиндексировать содержимое /images/favicon/, он должен откуда-то узнать, какие именно файлы там лежат, а так как вы запретили индексирование всех страниц сайта, поисковику будет неоткуда узнать точную ссылку на иконку и поэтому он скорее всего ничего не проиндексирует

Comment: А вообще иконка — это свойство страницы, и на разных страницах могут быть разные иконки, а если все страницы сайта запрещены для индексирования, то даже разрешённые для индексирования фавиконки будет некуда приткнуть, потому что страниц нет

Comment: Всем спасибо, я понял свою ошибку. Я особо не разбирался и просто закрыл индексацию всему сайту. Мне нужно закрыть индексацию только для некоторых документов и вопрос тогда отпадет.